# Wicket DropDownChoice Format

Tags: wicket, dropdownchoice

Whenever I do something like someString = object().name + " / " object2().name; in the toString() of an object, and load the array of objects into a wicket dropDownChoice,  the dropDownChoice disregards the spacing of the strings.. So I'd rather have something like:

```
                Role / Site
```

Drop Down Menu:  RoleName  / SiteName

but instead no matter how much spacing I put it will always display:

RoleName/SiteName in the drop down choice... any ideas?  I tried doing:

object().name + "&nbsp/&nbsp" object2()   because I wasn't sure how wicket processes the string into the option tags, but that didn't work either.

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out..

doing

```
       toString()
       {
          return "object().name + "&nbsp/&nbsp" object2().name"
       }

        this ended up working when I called:

        ssaIDRolesDropDownList.setEscapeModelStrings(false);

        //ssaIDRolesDropDownList is a reference to my dropDownChoice
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Wicket; Elements like dropdowns or the infamous input type="file"
are rendered OS specific:

[Preserve whitespace in html select element options using "white-space: pre" NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293536/preserve-whitespace-in-html-select-element-options-using-white-space-pre-not)

Comment: actually I just figured it out.. doing the &nbsp works when I implement setEscapeModelStrings(false) on the dropdownchoice reference.  Thanks though!