# How to keep whitespaces in the begining of select options?

Tags: html, css

I need to keep whitespaces in the begining of select options so I'm adding styles: `style="white-space: pre`, and rendered form is as below:

```
  <select id="doc_category" name="doc[category]" class="form-control select2 form-control">
        <option value="32" style="white-space: pre">G1</option>
        <option value="33" style="white-space: pre"> p1</option>
        <option value="34" style="white-space: pre"> p333</option>
        <option value="35" style="white-space: pre">G2</option>
        <option value="36" style="white-space: pre"> p3</option>
        <option value="37" style="white-space: pre">GłãWNA3</option>
        <option value="38" style="white-space: pre"> pod5</option>
    </select>
```

and whitespaces are gone.

Comment: Duplicated question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293536/preserve-whitespace-in-html-select-element-options-using-white-space-pre-not

Comment: If you want visual grouping you can use `<optgroup>` btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve whitespace in html select element options using "white-space: pre" NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293536/preserve-whitespace-in-html-select-element-options-using-white-space-pre-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `&nbsp;` instead of `<pre>` works for me:

```html
<select id="doc_category" name="doc[category]" class="form-control select2 form-control">
  <option value="32">G1</option>
  <option value="33">&nbsp;p1</option>
  <option value="34">&nbsp;p333</option>
  <option value="35">G2</option>
  <option value="36">&nbsp;p3</option>
  <option value="37">GłãWNA3</option>
  <option value="38">&nbsp;pod5</option>
</select>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

You should use option groups for that.

A nice simple example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, but also want main category to be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

place `&nbsp;` at the beginning OR (which is better since there is no real white-space present then) use **`padding-left:1em;`**