# how to display as it is data on html dropdown box coming from server?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, html-encode

Getting data from server as below

```
Test        Your    Code
New  Testing    Code
Opel Audi
```

> Above data have sapace between the words. i want to show text as it
>   is.

I have html select dropdown where i am rendering the server data.

> but i am not able to diplay data as it is coming form server, it is
>   showing one space in between the word. can anyone tell me how to fix
>   this?

```
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Test        Your    Code</option>
  <option value="saab">New  Testing    Code   </option>
  <option value="opel">Opel Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

check [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JT3j0peraAZcCVmTS2qy?p=preview)

Comment: try using `&nbsp;`

Comment: i am dynamically getting these data

Comment: @RyanC it is not possible to menually use &nbsp;

Comment: After you get the data replace white spaces with `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve whitespace in html select element options using "white-space: pre" NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293536/preserve-whitespace-in-html-select-element-options-using-white-space-pre-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML will remove any spaces following 1 space. Just replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space point)

```
str = str.replace(/\s/gmi, '&nbsp;');
```

edit: forgot semicolon

Comment: `&nbsp;` is the encoder. You can read more about `nbsp` here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 1):

you can use string replace method

str = str.replace("", '&nbsp');

Answer (score 1):

Try whitespace characters `&nbsp;` instead of spaces. In your case you need to modify text coming from server accordingly.