# Using <select> and <V-for>,how to preserve white space

Tags: html, vuejs2

I use select, and v-for to show values,
but when I have white space in values,like
"a  (white space)     a     -   (white space)    "
(***white space is real " ",it can't type here...***)
it only show "a a -" and return to backend;most white space be removed,
it's my code:

```
`<div class="form-group">
      <label>API:</label>
      <select id="service" v-model="selectedAllservice" class="form-control">
         <option v-for="t in allservice_name">[[ t ]]</option>
      </select>
</div>`
```

my present and data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuXue.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVgvt.png)

How can I preserve all the whitespace in the values?
Do it have any way to solve it?Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a simple json containing **allservice_name** data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserve whitespace in HTML select element options using "white-space: pre" NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293536/preserve-whitespace-in-html-select-element-options-using-white-space-pre-not)

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade
you means it?
0: "(get) b             b           -      "
1: "(get) test"
2: "(post) a            a     -"
3: "(post) get_hr_info"
4: "(post) test3"

Comment: @HaoWu
I know it can use v-html and use "&nbsp" to replace white space,but I want to know does it have other way to solve it?
like add some <tag> or css ....or other way

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing this, you can change the rendering option to `v-html`.

But using `v-html` can also expose your app to XSS attacks if you haven't sanitize your HTML string properly.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>API:</label>
  <select id="service" v-model="selectedAllservice" class="form-control">
    <option v-for="t in allservice_name" v-html="t"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```